# using size_t difference to copy a portion of a string

Tags: c++, size-t

I am trying to iterate through a string and copy chunks of information based off of an initial key value and a key value that identifies the end of the chunk of info. However when I try to subtract my initial and final values to find the length of the chunk im looking for, I receive a seemingly arbitrary value.

So the start and end indicies are found by:

```
currentstringlocation = mystring.find("value_im_looking_to_start_at, 0);
endlocation = mystring.find("value_im_looking_to_stop_at", currentstringlocation);
```

I'm then trying to do something like:

```
mystring.copy(newstring,(endlocation-currentlocation), currentlocation);
```

This however isn't giving me the results I want. Here's an excerpt from my code and the output it yields.

```
stringlocation2=topoinfo.find("\n",stringlocation+11);
topoinfo.copy(address,(stringlocation2-stringlocation+11),stringlocation+11);
cout << (stringlocation2-stringlocation+11) << "\n";
cout << stringlocation2 << "\t" << stringlocation+11 << "\n";
```

output:
25
59  56

So clearly the chunk of info I'm trying to capture spans 3 characters, however when I subtract the two I get 25. Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can work around it?

Comment: Are you sure what you are doing is supposed to be done with string operations and not a parser?

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating the length wrong, try instead something like:

```
topoinfo.copy(address, stringlocation2 - (stringlocaion + 11),
              stringlocation + 11);
```

After this, `address` will contain the copied string. Remember though: If `address` is a character array or a character pointer, then you *should* add the terminating `'\0'` character yourself!

A better solution to get a substring is to actually use the [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function:

```
std::string address = topoinfo.substr(stringlocation + 11,
                                      stringlocation2 - (stringlocaion + 11));
```

Comment: Of course. Thanks for pointing that out and for the method suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
topoinfo.copy(address,stringlocation2-(stringlocation+11),stringlocation+11);
cout << stringlocation2-(stringlocation+11) << "\n";
```

You got your brackets wrong.